# UITextView border in swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview

Is there any way to set the active border color and inactive border color to UITextView?
For example, if textview is focused to input text, then border color will be red, otherwise textview border color set to gray.
Thank you.

Comment: Not natively, you'd have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Keep in mind that red typical indicates an error. And don't forget to consider people with vision impairments.

Comment: thank you. that's the example. my goal is when textview is in input state then border to some color(for example green), and otherwise border to gray. Thanks for your concern and advice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way would be to implement [`textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618610-textviewdidbeginediting) and [`textViewDidEndEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618628-textviewdidendediting) from `UITextViewDelegate` in your class where you want to change `borderColor` property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

  ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textView.delegate = self
    self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
  }

  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor.cgColor
  } 

  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor.cgColor
  }
}
```